# How to get content of message from users in my site using twilio

Tags: php, twilio

How are you everyone?
My site is based on PHP.
I am new with twilio and building simple project with this.
So what I should implement is to send messages to users using twilio and then receive message from users again in my site.

```
<?php

// Update the path below to your autoload.php,
// see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
$sid = 'Azzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';
$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$message = $twilio->messages
                  ->create("+12099216581", // to
                           [
                               "body" => "This is test",
                               "from" => "+15324394442",
                               "statusCallback" => ""
                           ]
                  );

print($message->sid);
```

This is for sending message to one users that I am using now..
Then...

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\TwiML\MessagingResponse;

$response = new MessagingResponse();
$response->message('This is message 1 of 2.');
$response->message('This is message 2 of 2.');

echo $response;
```

I think this code will return text message to users with text...
If I am wrong, Please teach me...

So I am trying to do it now, but I can't know how to receive the content of message in my site.
If you are experience in this fields, Please teach me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the webhook for that messaging response

```
smsUrl = 'url';

$response   = $client->request("POST", "IncomingPhoneNumbers/$phone_id.json", ['auth' => [$sid, $token], 'form_params' => array("SmsUrl" => $webhook_url, "BundleSid" => $bundle_id)]);
```

this URL will post the incoming message and reply message